# In my main.cpp, called function variable through object claims it is undeclared

Tags: c++

first post here. I am creating a program that sorts arrays alphabetically, and displays the unsorted and sorted lists. However, when testing the sorting function through the Lab5.cpp, it claims the array pointer declared in the header and implementation .cpp is undeclared, despite the prototypes matching the actual function call. I posted a mediafire link, I can post the text if needed.

http://www.mediafire.com/?39xfxm3canjndte

```
//Lab 5.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student stu;

    stu.getStudent();  
    stu.displayStudent();
    stu.sortStudent(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray[]);
    system("pause");
};


//Student.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
      public:
             Student();
             void setStudent();
             int getStudent();
             int sortStudent(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray[]);
             void displayStudent();
             void displaySorted(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray);
      private:
             string names[50];
             int age[50];
             int size;
};        


//Student.cpp
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
                  setStudent();
};

void Student::setStudent()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
            age[i] = 0;
    }
};    

int Student::getStudent()
{
    string temp;
    cout << "Enter number of people <0 . . 50>" << endl << "> ";
    cin >> size;
    getline( cin, temp);
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
            cout << "Enter name " << i << " (lastname, firstname): ";
            getline( cin, names[i] );
            cout << "Enter age " << i << ": ";
            cin >> age[i];
            cout << endl;
            getline( cin, temp );
    }
};

int Student::sortStudent(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray[])
{
            *nameArray[i] = &name[i];
            *ageArray[i] = &age[i];


};

void Student::displayStudent()
{
    cout << "Original list" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
            cout << names[i] << setw(28) << age[i] << endl;
    }
};

void Student::displaySorted(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray)
{

};
```

Comment: Didnt see your code but the first thing comes to my mind is "extern". If you declared something in other files and want to use them , you have to declare it again but put extern before type

Comment: There's no array pointer declared in your header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement your required sortStudent method and the displayStudent method.

Ok, let's start out by

```
  1.  Tagging this as homework and c++
  2.  Give a print out of the error
    ~/Desktop/test/Student$ make
        g++ -c Student.cpp -o Student.o -I.  
        g++ -c Lab5.cpp -o Lab5.o -I.  
        Lab5.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
        Lab5.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
        Lab5.cpp:14: error: ‘nameArray’ was not declared in this scope
        Lab5.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
        Lab5.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
        Lab5.cpp:15: error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope
        make: *** [Lab5.o] Error 1
  3. Explain what you have tried, and what you are trying to do.
```

It looks to me like you are to implement the methods:
    int sortStudent(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray[]);
    void displaySorted(string *nameArray[], int *ageArray);

This would have allowed someone to quickly point out the mistake and get you
on your way.  I believe the error is due to the fact that you need to replace
the function stub in the `main()` function with a valid function call.  Also,
if this had been tagged `c` or `c++` it likely would have been downvoted to
close.  So, in closing, hope this helps and read the SO FAQ.